How to resolve glibc errors in conda enviroment installation?
I am a non root user in a Linux based cluster. It doesn't have docker nor I have privileges to install it. The base environment have GLIBC version 2.17. I am trying to install packages (like faiss-gpu, ollama etc.) which have higher GLIBC requirements. I don't want to break the system by upgrading base's GLIBC. I am confused that how should I handle this problem.
Upon searching I found multiple posts which to best of my knowledge indicated to install GLIBC and its dependencies in separate path and then configure before building or using patchelf to newer paths. I was unable to understand most of the information, but tried installing GLIBC in a separate conda environment using conda install conda-forge::libgcc-ng conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng vikky34v::glibc and changing environment variable using export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(conda info --base)/envs/your_env/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH, when I verify it using strings $(conda info --base)/envs/glibc/lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC" it shows 'GLIBC 2.33' . Despite this still when I try to install package they give GLIBC error (like

Package pyparsing conflicts for:
wheel -> packaging[version='>=20.2'] -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']
pytorch::faiss-gpu -> packaging -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
pytorch::faiss-gpu -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
Your installed version is: 2.17

If some one can simple down my options and how can I or should have proceeded for troubleshooting it will be of great help.

You may consider the opposite option: try to get the package with a lower glibc dependency. It is very seldom that a package need a newer glibc

You could try to compile the desired glibc version and put it in the folder you want and configure conda to look for it there. To install the libc from sources:
wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.34.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.34.tar.gz && cd glibc-2.34
mkdir glibc-build && cd glibc-build
../configure --prefix=/path/where/you/can/write/
make 
make install


OP explicitly told us that he has no root privileges, so it will not work. (last line). And why using sudo? If you choose prefix on your home (as one should do), you do not need sudo. (and GNU follows a good standard on where to put thing in own home).

Ah. I added sudo out of habit. You are right, no sudo is needed there

@MuslimbekAbduganiev Thanks for the reply. When I am trying to create the MAKEFILE I get error "*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make". I tried installing make from build in coda environment and exporting the path like "export PATH=$HOME/make-4.3/bin:$PATH" but it still keep showing me old version. After exporting path make --version's output is showing correct version i.e. 4.3 but the configure is still taking make's version from base. How can I proceed?

You probably don't have make at all. And you cannot install build-essentials as you don't have root/sudo access... Tough case

@MuslimbekAbduganiev Thanks for the reply. While in installation it gave make too old error to resolve it I installed make 4.3 from binary but glibc defaults o gmake version if present  so I had to hardcode it in the configure file to use make. It was able to generate make file but on running make it gives error "/usr/bin/install: missing destination file operand after ‘". Can you guide me how do I proceed?
